# Spring Security - POST request getting blocked by authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication, post

I have the following code in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("View","Modify","Delete")
    .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
    .and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
      .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
    .and()
      .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and()
      .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login/403")
    .and()
      .csrf();
}
```

When I make `GET` requests to `/api` I get through to the request handler without needing to authenticate, but `POST` requests are getting sent to the `403` page

I originally didn't have the `/api` lines at all, and had the same issue with `GET` working, but `POST` needing to authenticate.

The versions of libraries are:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.security-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
    <org.springframework.data-version>1.9.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.data-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.12</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <cglib-version>2.2.2</cglib-version>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core-version>2.6.3</com.fasterxml.jackson.core-version>
    <org.hibernate-version>4.1.7.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.37</mysql-version>
    <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
    <org.mockito-version>1.10.19</org.mockito-version>
    <org.hamcrest-version>2.0.0.0</org.hamcrest-version>
    <com.jayway.jsonpath-version>0.8.1</com.jayway.jsonpath-version>
</properties>
```

After more research I have added the following code, and that has fixed it, but I still don't understand why my original code doesn't work:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
{
    webSecurity
        .ignoring()
            // All of Spring Security will ignore the requests
            .antMatchers("/api/**"); // APIs use a key
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just FYI - no need to add thanks or appreciation, or explain how you tried but were unable to solve. That pretty much describes every question here.

Comment: @KerrinHardy I know you have csrf protection enabled but do you also have the csrf token included within the jsp form tags of the jsp page processing the HTTP post method? like this <input type="hidden"
 name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
 value="${_csrf.token}"/> also what versions of spring and spring-security are you using?

Comment: I had forgot to add the `csrf` input fields, so I have just done that, although that hasn't fix the issue. I am using jquery to post the request to the `api` pages. I've updated the question with the library versions.